# Meaning of "making collection rounds"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> And so, having put fear in the hearts of his Brighton Beach supplicants, Evsei Agron adopted the life of a Mafia don, holding court in local restaurants, ***making collection rounds*** in his chauffeured limousine, and pausing on street corners to dispense favors.

I don't understand the phrase "making collection rounds" in the sentence. What does it truly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“rounds” refers to a regular series of visits.

A common example is a doctor in a hospital “doing rounds” by visiting each patient in turn every day to check on their progress. A newspaper delivery person (unlike most other deliveries) could also make his rounds daily or weekly.

Mobsters are known to collect protection money from businesses in their territory, and presumably they would have regular routes to pass by each of the businesses they’re collecting from, similar to the more conventional cases above.